# How do I make 2 columns resize proportionally above a certain width, but have only one resize when the form is below that width?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application with 2 grid columns in the main window. When being resized, I want the right column to never go below 220 width, but the left column to continue to shrink. If the window is expanded enough, I want both columns to expand proportionally, with the left column double the size of the right column. I thought I could accomplish that with the following XAML...

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="220"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

But what happens, is when the right column reaches 220, they both stop resizing and the window just closes over the right column (starts covering the controls) as shown in the pics below. I now understand why it is doing this, but I can't figure out how to make it function the way I want it to.

This is what it looks like when the form is around 660 total width
[image: This is what it looks like when the form is around 660 total width]

This is what it looks like when squeezed below 660
[image: This is what it looks like when squeezed below 660]

This is what I want it to look like when squeezed below 660
[image: This is what I want it to look like when squeezed below 660]

Comment: Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the contents of the leftmost column. This should work like you want if you just add two simple `Grid` elements to the outer grid.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `DataTrigger` that if `ActualWidth` of column 2 equals `MinWidth` of column 2 then changes `Width` to `auto` to `ColumnDifinition` of column 1 should achieve your goal.

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*">
            <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource eqCvrt}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="c2" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="c2" Path="MinWidth"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Style>
        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="220" Name="c2"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Object.Equals(values[0], values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```